# How can I hold the max of a stack?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, max

Been banging my head against a wall for a week and cannot seem to get anywhere. I want to be able to get the max from the stack and keep it in the stack so in the end there is a only one value in the Stack and that is the max. I believe my algorithm to keep the max is correct, but I think my `pop` method is malfunctioning and I cannot figure out why. Any guidance is appreciated. Both files I am working with are included

```
 import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ListIterator;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class LinkedListStack {

        DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();

        public int size() {
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Stack is empty");
            }
            return list.size();

        }

        public void push(Integer s) { 
            list.add(s);

        }

        public Integer pop() {
            /* need help with this method */

        }

        public Integer top() {
            return list.iterator().next();

        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return list.isEmpty();

        }

        public String displayStack() {
            return (list.toString());
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            LinkedListStack stack = new LinkedListStack();

            int n, seed;
            File outputFile;
            File dir = new File(".");

            if (args.length > 0) {
                n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                seed = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            }else { 
                n  = 10;
                seed = 1;
            }

            if (args.length == 3) {
                outputFile = new File(args[2]);
            } else {
                outputFile = new File(dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "Files/testOut_Stack"); 
            }
            OutputWriter out = new OutputWriter(outputFile);

            Random r = new Random(seed);

            Integer nextval;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                nextval = r.nextInt(10000);

                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    stack.push(nextval);
                }

                if (nextval > stack.top()) {
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(nextval);    
                }



                /* retain the max value that you see among the integers generated in the stack. 
                 * In the end there should be only one integer in stack, which is the max value
                 */
            }

            // write the content of stack -- which is the max value -- to file
            out.writeOutput(stack.displayStack());
        }
    }


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;

import csci3230.hw3.OutputWriter;

public class DoublyLinkedList<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    private int n;        // number of elements on list
    private Node pre;     // sentinel before first item
    private Node post;    // sentinel after last item

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        pre  = new Node();
        post = new Node();
        pre.next = post;
        post.prev = pre;
    }

    // linked list node helper data type
    private class Node {
        private Item item;
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (n == 0);
        // your code
    }
    public int size() {  
        return n;
        // your code
    }

    // add the item to the list
    public void add(Item item) {
        Node last = post.prev;
        Node x = new Node();
        x.item = item;
        x.next = post;
        x.prev = last;
        post.prev = x;
        last.next = x;
        n++;
        // your code
    }

    public ListIterator<Item> iterator()  { return new DoublyLinkedListIterator(); }

    // assumes no calls to DoublyLinkedList.add() during iteration
    private class DoublyLinkedListIterator implements ListIterator<Item> {
        private Node current      = pre.next;  // the node that is returned by next()
        private Node lastAccessed = null;      // the last node to be returned by prev() or next()
                                               // reset to null upon intervening remove() or add()
        private int index = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() { 
            return (index < n); // your code
        }
        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return (index > 0);
            // your code
        }
        public int previousIndex() { 
            return (index - 1);
            // your code
        }
        public int nextIndex() { 
            return (index + 1);
            // your code
        }

        public Item next() {
            if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            lastAccessed = current;
            Item item = current.item;
            current = current.next; 
            index++;
            return item;
            // your code
        }

        public Item previous() {
            if (!hasPrevious()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            current = current.prev;
            index--;
            lastAccessed = current;
            return current.item;
            // your code
        }

        // replace the item of the element that was last accessed by next() or previous()
        // condition: no calls to remove() or add() after last call to next() or previous()
        public void set(Item item) {
            if (lastAccessed == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
            lastAccessed.item = item;
            // your code
        }

        // remove the element that was last accessed by next() or previous()
        // condition: no calls to remove() or add() after last call to next() or previous()
        public void remove() { 
            if (lastAccessed == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
            Node x = lastAccessed.prev;
            Node y = lastAccessed.next;
            x.next = y;
            y .prev = x;
            n--;
            if (current == lastAccessed) {
                current = y;
            }
            else {
                index--;
            }
            lastAccessed = null;
            // your code
        }

        // add element to list 
        public void add(Item item) {
            Node x = current.prev;
            Node y = new Node();
            Node z = current;
            y.item = item;
            x.next = y;
            y.next = z;
            z.prev = y;
            y.prev = x;
            n++;
            index++;
            lastAccessed = null;
            // your code
        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (Item item : this)
            s.append(item + " ");
        return s.toString();




  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to add every value to the "stack"? Otherwise, compare the value that is being added and don't add it if it is less than the value of `peek` (or `top` perhaps in your case).

Comment: I like the idea, if the value being added into the stack is greater than 'top' then would I have to pull 'top' out and 'push' the new value in?

Comment: `DoublyLinkedList.add()` adds to the end of the list. `list.iterator().remove()` removes the first element in the list. That is *queue* functionality, not *stack*. On top of that, `list.iterator().previous()` after *already* removing the value will fail, i.e. return something else or die. Since you have a `DoublyLinkedList` with easy access to both first and last element in the list, why not add methods `removeFirst()` and `removeLast()`, each returning the removed element. That way your stack logic is so much easier, with having to use the iterator.

Comment: @KevinO, also please excuse my incorrect formatting, new to the site

Comment: Yes, pop old value and push new 'max'. Dependent upon the ability to hold only a single value. Do note potential issues raised by @Andreas.

Comment: @Andreas how do you suppose I fix this? Thank you for your input

Comment: @jkgram43 I already made some recommendation for fixing your code. I suggest you search the web, which will have a gazillion examples of doubly-linked lists and stacks. Do your research.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the first integer you pop as a temporary "largestValue" and compare every subsequent integer you pop with it to see whether you should replace it. At the very of your function, pop all values and add the largestValue back onto it.

Comment: If I could figure out why my `pop` is not working I could do that, do you have any recommendations for fixing it?

Comment: If you do not know its fine, I just have absolutely no clue

Comment: Sorry for the late response. To pop, simply remove the last added entry. For a linked list, just make the item before the last point to nothing. (eg. Item1 -> Item2 -> Item3 becomes Item1 -> Item2 -> null). But remember to save the content of the last item because you need to return it.